# Can RegEx be used with Meteor "check" package?

Tags: regex, meteor, meteor-helper

I am relatively new to Meteor (and really like it -- thank you! framework authors).

My question is about the [check](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check_package) package: Is there a way to call check with a RegEx pattern to validate input? I read all of the documentation for the package at the link I provided; the word "pattern" is mentioned several times, but (afaik) it was not meant to refer to a regular expression pattern.

I'm hoping I am missing something, and someone will be able to point me to a way to implement a `check()` call that uses a regular expression to validate a string.

Comment: I think the documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/matchpatterns) is pretty clear as to what patterns are supported. But since it just throws an exception `Match.Error` you could easily implement your own version that checks a regex.

Comment: My question wasn't a criticism of the Meteor documentation. The authors have done an excellent job. But I wasn't asking for subjective opinions about the clarity of the documentation, either.

Comment: too bad you focused on that part of my comment, and not the constructive suggestion. Anyhow, it wasn't meant as criticism of your question. I even up-voted the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with the `Match.Where()` pattern.

```
Match.Where(function(str){
  check(str, String);
  var regexp = /* your RegExp */;
  return regexp.test(str);
});
```

(You are right that the 'patterns' referred to by the `check` package are not regular expression patterns; they are the 'patterns' listed in the documentation.)

Comment: Oh, ok now I see. I overlooked that pattern, which is nice since it lets you implement whatever custom check functionality you need.